# Permalinks not working using wordPress Networking with custom post types

Tags: multisite, permalinks

Hay All, I've setup a WordPress network and have a couple of websites. Within these 'sub-websites' have a created a new custom post type called 'courses'. When i create a new 'course' a sample permalink would be

www.mysite.com/site1/course/my-course-name

However, this doesn't link to the article in the question. Is this a normal error with wordpress?

How, can i fix this? I think there's an issue with the .htaccess file WP generated for me.

Comment: Hmm, odd. Updating the paralinks seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: It's 'permalink' not 'paralink' and yes, clicking save flushes the cache.

Comment: paralinks sounds cooler though :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a post about it a week ago http://en.bainternet.info/2011/custom-post-type-getting-404-on-permalinks
But a simple save changes in the permalink admin panel should fix it for you.